# Javascript in Windows 8 App

Tags: javascript, windows-8, winjs

I have the following code in `home.js` of the default NavigationApp:

```
(function () {
"use strict";

WinJS.UI.Pages.define("/pages/home/home.html", {
    // This function is called whenever a user navigates to this page. It
    // populates the page elements with the app's data.
    ready: function (element, options) {
        var submit = document.getElementById("submitBtn");
        submit.addEventListener("click", myFunc());
    }
});

function myFunc() {
    // Do some stuff here
}

})();
```

The problem I have is that the function `myFunc()` executes immidiately the app starts, and not on the pressing of the submit button as I expected; why is this?

Comment: Change `submit.addEventListener("click", myFunc());` to `submit.addEventListener("click", myFunc);`

Comment: Thanks, your answer also worked - although it worked too well and stopped the event handler being added :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding the result of `myFunc()` to your listener, you want to be doing

`submit.addEventListener("click", myFunc)`

to add the function as the callback instead of the result of the function.

Answer (score 1):

Your code calls `myfunc` immediately and passes the result to `addEventListener`.

You need to pass the function itself by removing the `()`.